# how to add a setonscrollistener process in listview

Tags: android

I m creating a list view .. now i want to create a setonscrolllistener method with this activity by which i can see 7 items at a time then when i scroll bottom then next 7 items will display and so on.. but dont know the process.please help guys

here is my code..

```
public class TenderActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_tender);

        String[] tenders={"tender1","tender2","tender3","tender4","tender5","tender6","tender7","tender8","tender9","tender10","tender11","tender12"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tenders));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use the method [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) an then set the ScrollListener to your ListView.

```
public class TenderActivity extends ListActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_tender);

            String[] tenders={"tender1","tender2","tender3","tender4","tender5","tender6","tender7","tender8","tender9","tender10","tender11","tender12"};
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tenders));
            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setOnScrollListener(yourScrollListener);
    }
```